# Restoring Apple's JavaAppletPlugin.plugin after Java Update 2012-006

Tags: java, macos, updates

So, I've discovered that some of my Java web apps have stopped functioning after applying the java update released by Apple on October 16th, 2012.

The [tech notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5493%20tech%20notes) indicate that Apple has removed the web app plug-in from OS X and that you need to download it from Oracle directly.

The problem with this is that Oracle only offers a 7x version of the plug-in and my apps require a 6x version, which I haven't been able to find.

So, can anybody point me to where I could find a copy of JavaAppletPlugin.plugin that I believe existed in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ prior to being destroyed?

And no, there is no chance that the vendor will be providing an updated version of the software which is compatible with Java 7 anytime soon.

Thanks All.

Comment: If the application only works under Java 6, wouldn't it also be broken for any Windows user with an up-to-date system?

Comment: Yes, the problem exists for anyone running Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to find this, but the solution to this issue can be found via this helpdesk article from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

**Here something important to note.** I've found that even after following these steps I still have problems when attempting to open a .jnlp file from within the Mac OSX user interface.  To successfully load a java web start program, you'll probably have to switch to the terminal then execute the following code (username$ is just the prompt for terminal newbies):

```
username$ javaws /path/to/file.jnlp
```

Feel free to contact me with any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, google chrome for mac is 32-bit and do not support Java 7.
Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

Comment: Thanks @XingxingWoo, but I can't create a symbolic link to a file that doesn't exist anymore.  I believe your solution will work, but only if I can find a place to download the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin file that was deleted by Apple's update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaplugin/

You could also try manually copying the old version of the plugin package over the new one.