# MacOS Java Control Panel Missing on Mojave

Tags: java, macos

I recently updated to Mojave and updated to Java 11 JDK and noticed that my Java Control Panel in my System Preference is missing. I tried doing a general search for it but nothing shows up. I also check if its Java JDK and JRE is install and they are. Is there a way to add it back to my System Preferences or if its possible to locate it in my systems?

Comment: Did you update it from Java?

Comment: Oracle no longer intends for end-users to install Java explicitly.  Apps such as Swing and JavaFX are expected to be delivered with their own bundled Java implementation. Only developers and server-side sysadmins will be installing Java explicitly, and that will be a regular JDK without the user-level integration you saw with that control panel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> They removed **Java Control Panel** in `Java 11`.

Open this release notes [Removal of Java Deployment Technologies](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#JDK-8185077), it says

> The Java Plugin and Java WebStart technologies that were deprecated in JDK 9 and marked as candidates for removal in JDK 10 have now been removed. Please note that the Java Control Panel, which was used for configuring the deployment technologies, has also been removed along with the shared system JRE (but not the server JRE) and the JRE Auto-Update mechanism. More details are available in this [white paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf).

Also,  If you go through this web page, [JDK 11 Is Released!](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/jdk-11-is-released)

There is the last bullet point where it says

> The deployment stack, required for Applets and Web Start Applications has been removed. This includes the Java Control Panel used for configuring the deployment technologies, the shared system JRE (but not the server JRE), and the JRE Auto-Update mechanism.

Comment: Is there any replacement for configuring some of the settings that were previously exposed via the control panel?

Comment: I feel you have to hack the reg if in windows. Not aware of Mac.

Comment: I need to add a website/url to the security exception list - not sure how it would be done.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 21):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

1. Open a new finder window and navigate to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/`. There you will find a file named `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`.
2. Control + Click this file and choose `Show Package Contents` from the contextual menu.
3. Inside the package, navigate to `/Contents/Home/bin/`.
4. Double click the `ControlPanel` file to display the Java Control Panel. Change any settings as you wish and then save it.
5. From now on, the panel will be available as always from `“Apple” menu > System Preferences...`

**Note**: if you don't find the `JavaAppletPlugin.plugin` file inside the `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/` folder, open the `Terminal.app` and create a symlink from the original:

`sudo ln -s /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967217/2394994)

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you!!

Comment: There's no such file as "JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" on my system (MacOS Ventura 13.3.1). All I have is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk

Comment: There is no folder `/System/Library/Java/` under Sonoma.