# How to access Java Console now that Java Control Panel has been removed

Tags: java, macos

I've recently updated to Java 12.

Since Java 11 they've removed the Java Control Panel.  More info about that here: [MacOS Java Control Panel Missing on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176089/macos-java-control-panel-missing-on-mojave)

Since there's no longer a Control Panel, how do I see the Java Console?  Or view/change Java settings in general?

I am using Mac OS X 10.13.6 and Eclipse 2019-03 for my IDE.

Comment: What Java-related settings are you looking to change, specifically?

Comment: @JacobG. Mostly I want to view the Java Console.  It would also be nice to see what version of Java OS X thinks I have installed to make sure it agrees with what I get when I type "java -version" in a terminal

Comment: Java Plugin, Web Start and the Deployment Stack were removed, so I believe there is no Java Console and no settings to view/change anymore...

Comment: All apps should default to use `JAVA_HOME`, which should be placed in your bashrc. MacOS itself doesn't need Java, and both Eclipse and Intellij IDE allow you to specify multiple installed Java versions across different projects