# Java control panel missing on macOS?

Tags: java, macos

I could not find the java control panel on my macOS after the installation of Java JDK.

I tried searching on the web but couldn't find any solution for the problem.

**How to find to the Java Control Panel on macOS ?**

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_controlpanel.xml

Comment: see this [MacOS Java Control Panel Missing on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176089/macos-java-control-panel-missing-on-mojave/53176853).

Answer (score 0):

```
MacOS 10.5 version and later. JDK installed location will be 
in /usr/libexec/..

I guess you’re trying to set your JAVA_HOME. 

Follow below steps
1. Install jdk and open Terminal
2. run 'java -version'
3. Setting java home
run 'export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)'
4. To check 'echo $JAVA_HOME'
```